# pygame returns string index error when assigning colour

Tags: python, pygame, wordle-game

I am trying to create a wordle clone in pygame. My function to determine the colour of letters (`determine_colour`) is currently posing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/e9773df3e08e9b22/main.py", line 77, in <module>
    colour = determine_colour(GUESSES[i], j)
  File "/tmp/sessions/e9773df3e08e9b22/main.py", line 34, in determine_colour
    if letter == ANSWER[j]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

My code is as follows:

```
import random
import pygame

word_options = ("NANCY")
ANSWER  = random.choice(word_options).upper()


WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 700
MARGIN = 10
T_MARGIN = 100
B_MARGIN = 100
LR_MARGIN = 100


GREY = (225, 227, 229)
GREY_FILLED = (120, 124, 126)
GREEN = (6,214,160)
YELLOW = (255, 209, 102)

INPUT = ""
GUESSES = []
ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
UNGUESSED = ALPHABET
GAME_OVER = False

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Nancdle")

def determine_colour(guess, j):
  letter = guess[j]

  if letter == ANSWER[j]:
    return GREEN

    #yellow
  if letter in ANSWER:
    return YELLOW
    
    #grey
  return GREY_FILLED
    
  
SQ_SIZE = (WIDTH-4*MARGIN-2*LR_MARGIN) // 5
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("free sans bold", SQ_SIZE)
FONT_SMALL = pygame.font.SysFont("free sans bold", SQ_SIZE//2)
def determine_unguessed_letters(guesses):
  guessed_letters = "".join(guesses)
  unguessed_letters = ""
  for letter in ALPHABET:
    if letter not in guessed_letters:
      unguessed_letters = unguessed_letters+letter
  return unguessed_letters
#screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
white = (255, 255, 255)
#animation loop
animating = True
while animating:

  screen.fill(white)
  determine_unguessed_letters(GUESSES)
  
  letters = FONT_SMALL.render(UNGUESSED, False, GREY_FILLED)
  surface = letters.get_rect(center = (WIDTH//2, T_MARGIN//2))
  screen.blit(letters, surface)
  
  y = T_MARGIN
  for i in range(6):
    x = LR_MARGIN
    for j in range(0,5):
      square = pygame.Rect(x, y, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, square, 2)
      #to add past letters/words
      if i < len(GUESSES):
        colour = determine_colour(GUESSES[i], j)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, square)
        letter = FONT.render(GUESSES[i][j], False, (255,255,255))
        surface = letter.get_rect(center = (x+SQ_SIZE//2, y+SQ_SIZE//2))
        screen.blit(letter, surface)
        
      # user text input (next guess)
      if i == len(GUESSES) and j < len(INPUT):
        letter = FONT.render(INPUT[j], False, (0, 0, 0))
        surface = letter.get_rect(center=(x+SQ_SIZE//2, y+SQ_SIZE//2))
        screen.blit(letter, surface)
      x += SQ_SIZE + MARGIN
    y += SQ_SIZE + MARGIN
  
    
  #to update screen
  pygame.display.flip()
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    #so you can close window
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      animating = False
    
    
    
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
        if len(INPUT) > 0:
          INPUT = INPUT[:len(INPUT) - 1]
      if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
        if len(INPUT) == 5:
          GUESSES.append(INPUT)
          UNGUESSED = determine_unguessed_letters(GUESSES)
          GAME_OVER = True if INPUT == ANSWER else False
          INPUT = ""
      elif event.key in range(pygame.K_a, pygame.K_z + 1):
        # any other letter keys pressed
        if len(INPUT) < 5 and not GAME_OVER:
          INPUT = INPUT + event.unicode.upper()
      elif event.key in [pygame.K_BACKSPACE, pygame.K_DELETE]:
        INPUT = INPUT[:-1]  # don't need to check length
```

I have tried several iterations of the for loop types, changed the code for the determine colour function, checked my input code, and looked through the code for word selection, all to no avail. I would expect the word "AZNCY" being inputted to be coloured yellow, grey, green, green, green.

Answer (score 0):

your variable ANSWER is consist of one letter.
`random.choice('xyz')`->returning the one letter, so when you try to access ANSWER[number>0] you will automatically get the error of index ranging. Next, time try to read errors, I hope it helps.

EDIT:
Sorry OP, I thought my answer was enough to get how to fix it.
Try to split your word NANCY in ANSWER like that ANSWER = ['N','A','N','C','Y'].
Hope it`s your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the indexing problem is because near the beginning where you have these two statements:

```
word_options = ("NANCY")
ANSWER = random.choice(word_options).upper()
```

This first line sets `word_options` to the single string (`"NANCY"`), and then the second line sets `ANSWER` to single **letter** of that.

This can be fixed it by making `word_options` a **`tuple`** of strings by adding a trailing comma — which is probably what you intended and thought you were doing by putting the string in parentheses:

```
word_options = ("NANCY",)  # Note added comma.
ANSWER = random.choice(word_options).upper()
```

Then `random.choice()` will set `ANSWER` to the entire **string** "NANCY", not merely to a single letter of it.

After also setting `GUESSES = ["AZNCY"]` for testing purposes, the `IndexError` no longer occurred and the following was displayed on the screen:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently a beginner, but hopefully, this insight might provide a solution:

Since `j` is out of range when guessing, check all instances where it matters if you're indexing from `0` because when you have a list Python indexes from `0`.

Example:

- A B C etc.
- 0 1 2 etc.

Or this might be the thing, perhaps if it's `==` instead?

```
if i < len(GUESSES) <----------- THIS
  colour = determine_colour(GUESSES[i], j)
```